# How to set more than one props in Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

React JSX

```
<div {...props}></div>
```

Vue

```
<div v-bind="$props"></div>
```

Angular

```
// how to do?
```

Comment: Angular doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14545

Answer (score 0):

You decorate properties with the `@Input()` decorator on the component's class

```
@Component({
  template: 'someHtml',
  selector: 'my-component'
})
class MyComponent() {
  @Input() prop1;
  @Input() prop2;
}
```

and set them in the template of the consuming component with property binding

`<my-component [prop1]="someValue" [prop2]="anotherValue"></my-component>`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I want to set props in one Input field like examples.

Comment: That is not supported in Angular

Comment: If you are looking to access the properties of a parent component you can ask for the instance of a component in the components hierarchy through dependency injection. constructor(private parentComponent: ParentComponentsClass) then you have access to all the properties of the parent component through this.parentComponent.

Answer (score 0):

If props is an array you can iterate with *ngFor

```html
<div *ngFor="let prop of props">
    <p>{{prop}}</p>
</div>
```